# C# how create WebException with Response status code

Tags: c#, exception, http-status-codes, webexception

I make some fake class, that should have same behavior as original one. 
Original class sometimes throws WebExceptions (with `StatusCode` in response from server).

I want repeat this behavior without any connection.
So, how can i create `new WebException(..., ..., ..., ...)` with needed `StatusCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part here is that while [WebException(String, Exception, WebExceptionStatus, WebResponse)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2zywh13(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor is freely available, the `HttpWebResponse` is stated to be created only through `HttpWebRequest` (there are constructors, but they are obsolete).

So, since `WebException` accepts abstract `WebResponse` rather than `HttpWebResponse`, I suggest creating a class `MockHttpWebResponse` or something. I don't know which variables you need exactly, so instead I'll link you to [HttpWebResponse source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs) for you to scavenge essential variables from.

Then you use this class in constructor like here:

```
new WebException(message, null, WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, new MockHttpWebResponse(statusCode))
```

...or something similar. I think you know best what's needed for your scenario. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to customize a class to increase the HTTP Status Code:

```
public class HttpWebException : WebException
{
    public int HttpStatusCode { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflections to accomplish that. In the following example i created a web exception with response i adjusted (also using reflections).

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
ActivateCallback(responseCallback, response, url, string.Empty);

var fieldStatusCode = response.GetType().GetField("m_StatusCode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
{
    var statusCodeNew = (HttpStatusCode)403;
    fieldStatusCode.SetValue(response, statusCodeNew);
}


string responceBody = "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"AF429\",\"message\":\"Too many requests. Method=GetContents, PublisherId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}}";

var propStream = response.GetType().GetField("m_ConnectStream", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responceBody));
    //response.ResponseStream = ms;//((System.Net.ConnectStream)(response.ResponseStream))
    propStream.SetValue(response, ms);
    ms.Position = 0;


WebException ex1 = new WebException();
var fieldResponce = ex1.GetType().GetField("m_Response", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
{
    fieldResponce.SetValue(ex1, response);
}
e = null;
throw ex1;
```